# Why do I see old version of webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to write a vuejs project, and when I run `vue-cli-service serve`, it builds without errors. But when I go to see the page, it is blank. In fact, the title on it does not match the title in index.html.

The code is:
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SHVB Frontend</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="./src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

App.vue

```
<script setup>
import AdminRegisterWindow from "./components/LoginButton.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <AdminRegisterWindow/>
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

main.js. Removing use(router) doesn't fix the issue

```
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import router from "../router/index.js"
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

index.js (router)

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'


const routes = [
    {
        path: "/:catchAll(.*)",
        redirect: '/index.html', // I have also tried '/'
    },
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

export default router
```

jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I don't believe the source cause can be in LoginButton component, plus the code there is long, so I will only add it if it is needed for additional context. So now when I build this, when I open index.html in devtools I see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vue App</title>
  <script defer src="/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script><script defer src="/js/app.js"></script></head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, not only it is blank, even the title doesn't match the one I have in index.html!

What do I do? How do I fix it?

Comment: Is that also the case when bypassing the cache (ctrl+F12)? Is javascript enabled in the browser?

Comment: "even the title doesn't match the one I have in index.html" - in which way? Are there errors in the console? In case this is cache issue, make sure you force the reload (ctrl+f5) and delete build cache in node_modules/.cache/

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @EstusFlask in the screenshot you can see the title is "Vue App", while in index.html it is "SHVB Frontend". There are no errors in the console. I'm not using any proxy/etc, I literally just build it in my editor and open the page.

Comment: @Pieterjan yes and yes.

Comment: Please, clarify what exactly you do. "open the page" - which url? The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , currently it lacks a way to reproduce, you surely won't have this behaviour when initializing vue project from scratch. Since you have a problem with vue-cli-service, this is primarily Vue CLI problem, not vue. index.html that you posted looks like Vite index and not Vue CLI (specifically <script type="module" src="./src/main.js"> part). It's unknown how you could mix Vite and Vue CLI, this suggests that something went wrong on your side

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm really new to Vue (literally my first project) so I don't even understand the difference between Vite and Vue-cli. I copied index.html from the tutorial. Removing that line (script part) does not help the issue, I've tried it. The link I open is http://localhost:8081 (port 8080 is binded to another process). I believe that copying the code I've given, adding an empty vue.config.js file and a non-empty component to App.vue (so that you just have something on the page) would be a mcve.

Comment: Which tutorial? It looks like you try to solve a problem that shouldn't have existed in the first place. If you don't know the difference then consider sorting it out first, as this is necessary to end up with a workable project. Vue docs cover both https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html#project-scaffolding . "vue.config.js" is a thing that belongs to Vue CLI, it's outdated but still workable tool. Consider starting the project from scratch with one of these tools and following the official guides to minimize the risk of unusual problems which the question shows